# BottomNavigationView implementation for multiple users

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface

I have a question about how I can correctly implement the adaptation of my interface for multiple user states (Registered and unregistered). I want my bottomNavigationView to open fragments relative to user states, but I don't know how to do it properly. Do I just need to save the state in sharedPreferences, and just check this state when the application starts, and relative to this already create the bottomNavigationView I need?

As I said earlier, the only idea to implement this is to compare the value from sharedPreferences.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.